# Flowtype - making a sealed empty object

Tags: flowtype

Flow's docs say: `When you create an object without any properties, you create an unsealed object type in Flow.` Is it possible to create a sealed object without properties?

My use case is as follows. I want to initialize `state` to an empty object, and give state the following type:

```
type EmployeesViewState = {|
  employeesRequest?: Request<Array<Employee>>,
  geosRequest?: Request<Array<Geo>>,
|};
```

The error I get when I try to assign an empty object is

```
 33:   state: EmployeesViewState = {};
                                   ^^ object literal. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
 33:   state: EmployeesViewState = {};
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ exact type: object type
```

Of course, since I don't have the requests available yet, I cannot assign them. I also can't assign `undefined` to the object because the state is defined with pipes, i.e. it is an exact type.

I can trick flow by saying `const a: any = {}; state = a;` but that seems really hacky. Any other ways of tackling this issue?

Comment: You could consider making the properties not optional, and having them be nullable instead. e.g. `employeesRequest: ?Request<Array<Employee>>,` then default with `employeesRequest: null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly one of Flow's warts. However, it has a fairly simple workaround. Just pass your object through `Object.freeze`:

`Object.freeze({})`

Of course this only works if you weren't going to mutate it, but I find that in cases like this I rarely want to anyway.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a type declaration that uses this method? When I try this I get an error, see [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAogWzKKBeKBvOALigGdgAnASwDsBzAXygB8oB5RAKwgGNgA6AGbkIEAF4QAFHnoBKANxA).