# How should union of Objects with optional properties be defined with Flow?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have a function that deals with two type of parameters: string and object. There are 3 different object structure expected. That makes up to 4 possibles types:

```
type URL = string;
type Item = {| href: string |};
type ItemList = {| results: Item[] |};
type Params = {| offset?: number, limit?: number |};
```

So the function's options type is:

```
type Options = URL | Item | ItemList | Params;
```

And here's the actual function:

```
// No properties of "Params" are required
// so if they're all omitted, Params === {}
function request(opts: Options = {}) {
  if (typeof opts === 'string') {
    return 'opts is an URL';
  }

  if (typeof opts.href === 'string') {
    return 'opts is an item';
  }

  if (Array.isArray(opts.results)) {
    return 'opts is a list of items';
  }

  // Three of the four types are caught
  // we're left with "Params" which may or may not
  // have a "offset" and "limit" property.
  // Destructuring to undefined values is fine here.
  // Still, flow complains about the type not being met.
  const { offset, limit } = opts;
  return 'opts are parameters';
}
```

Flow is complaining about a few things:

1. `opts = {}` throws an incompatibility error. Since no properties of `Params` are required, shouldn't empty objects match it too? Note that `opts = { offset: undefined }` clears the error.
2. Properties "offset" and "limit" are declared not found. Since none of them are required, shouldn't `undefined` be valid values? And thus destructuring fine?

To summarize my question:

How do you define a type that accepts different types of object, with one having no required properties?

Edit: [run the flow code in your browser](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCqASgDJgC8YAzhgE4CWAdgOYDcmuBAkhngLaUwAbwA+YABZ08UAFw16zFmFEBfDtnxheA0g1pCxYadQCuMDNXk7+AbQC6K9Zy0AFAIZ13-aofFwoKGo8DAB+eSZTfgAjPDoAGjAYBn4GMIio2LonDS4wAHkcDAY4Jl8qEnJRAAKbFW0+fj0DcQ8vHw5UYGAwADk4MBw6OHw6YrxfALAAIjbvammwTwJpAEdTBmkAEy6e6gGGKDAMCTwsAHJpJZgYMDhUjD4txLmfSgoqYVVUKFMmAGNiqVjHh1hMMAAKEaWeSFIFlQyqACUIlQYDAhzAEM0eCm0PKHzA51ojFY5xRwjR6JBGFMdCYRPxGN87gZlXOHHR33RVMx2K4eKK1AAdFIZO8qMTFGSKVT0dJafTGULmUsGWkBByqdywLyjhCAIJ0LxYYX6I0mqFC4UmcyWJGy6k0ukM85M-RLJL6DB3I4anxarlUqndMAAFTFBCmJwIUDgdOOXBZV3+7lMLAkGBDPQQeEuBBgMh9CDSEhmrwWYAQEgY-zL-HcWDu2QbTaYcCz6NDEncADcCO4ZgEgiFFqytjNkg9FkMRnFsMLs2AACLguimQF0pTHAZ-LYyZh4Ce99wwUwTVVQQ+SOJ4RddnoAZWKN0SsEQYH+9xwMHczBZ0Txj6MaJlo7Y+rE278CE96fqUBjCL6I4YIkU5pGAqhCPinLOkqboqssgyeN4IRxNQWrfEAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Flowtype - making a sealed empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399022/flowtype-making-a-sealed-empty-object) for an answer to your first question.

For your second, the answer basically is that Flow does not fully support this sort of type refinement. [Disjoint unions](https://flow.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions/) were designed for this use case, though you do have to add a discriminator property to all of your objects. Obviously, this will require some nontrivial changes to your code. It's up to you to decide if this is feasible.

If it's not feasible, the best thing to do is probably to just cast through `any` in this function, and make sure you provide a type annotation for the return value. It looks like it's small enough that it's easy for a human to reason about, so the benefit of typechecking here may not be worth the effort. Of course that's a judgement call that is best left to you.