# How to specify an empty object in Flow type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say I have a variable that can either be a JavaScript error object or an empty object, how would I specify the empty object in Flow?

One possibility that I've tried as seen in various places (e.g. [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2977)), looks like this:

```
const err: Error | {||} = {};
```

But this gives the following flow error:

```
1: const exact: {||} = {};
                       ^ Cannot assign object literal to `exact` because inexact object literal [1] is incompatible with exact object type [2].
References:
1: const exact: {||} = {};
                       ^ [1]
1: const exact: {||} = {};
                ^ [2]
```

See [it live here](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIbCgLhgbwD7YL4wC8WeA3AFBA). the `||` notation is evidently shorthand for `$Exact<>` as explained [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-exact). So I can't see why exactly this is failing.

What it is saying is that the empty object I'm trying to assign to `err` is an "inexact object literal". I get that it's an object literal, which in fact does not match the "exact object type" of an empty object.

What I don't understand is why it is inexact. It seems pretty exact in that at runtime it is an empty object. Can someone explain the logic here and/or how it may be possible to specify that `err` is either an `Error` or an empty object?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because Flow sees it as an [unsealed object](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unsealed-objects). Might be easiest to just use `({}: any)`.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399022/flowtype-making-a-sealed-empty-object/44444793#44444793

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2977

Comment: @JamesKraus the solution in the stackoverflow link you provided does not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`$Shape<T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-shape) to specify an object with no properties:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBBBOsHlECMBWUC8UCi8D2sUAPlACQDKAFgIaQA8A3kUQL4B8AUBwMZ4B2AZ2Ax4ALhGIU6LHwgB3HPlgAKAEQAhADbVKqgJRdeg4RAC2YUAjTi4kq9KgMWh-kKh9+ZiyBvwk9zEdkbUpxACZnIA))

```
type errOrObj = Error | $Shape<{||}>

const err: errOrObj = new Error("Blah")

const emptyObj: errOrObj = {}

const nonempty: errOrObj = {blah: 2} // Error
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
const err: Error | {||} = Object.freeze({});
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBBBOsHlECMBWUC8UCi8D2sUAPlAN5FEC+A3AFC0DGeAdgM7AzwBcniK6WZhADuOfLAAUAIgBCAGwCGACykBKOoxbsYAWzCgEaHnD6GBUMxAbAAdADNYECAC8IE0pXX0mbDsxYQeqDG8EhmmGTIiko8AEw0QA))

See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2977#issuecomment-390613203 and https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unsealed-objects